# Bind column header visibility without losing global style

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, styles

I want to bind the column header visibility of a wpf listview to a dependency property without losing the global style (expression dark) I used.

I defined a style:

```
<Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ColumnHeaderVisibility}" />
</Style>
```

Then I applied it like this:

```
<GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
```

I'm using the expression dark theme. It's imported via MergedDictionaries and can be changed in runtime.

Everything is fine when the column header is invisible. But when visible it is shown in default windows style, because setting the ColumnHeaderContainerStyle overrides the expression dark style.

Using "BasedOn" on the original style is no option, because all resources are dynamic due to the requirement to change style in runtime. BasedOn only works on static resources, which won't allow changing in runtime.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but you can try to base style on the default style.

```
<Style x:Key="myHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ColumnHeaderVisibility}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Tried this. The style won't inherit from the default style (maybe because it's referenced as staticresource and is resolved during compile time where no style is set yet).